# JS code works perfectly in JSFiddle, but won't work in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I made  script that changes the active Bootstrap tab based on the current day. As you should see, it works great on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sammagee/p0grh76n/24/).

However, I have tried adding this to my meteor application in several ways, including once without "meteorizing" it at all. This didn't work, so I tried looking it up and ended up wrapping the tabbed navigation in a `<template name="nav">`. I then tried loading the script within a `Template.nav.onRendered` block. This didn't work either and now I'm stumped.

**Edit:** If anyone else has the same problem, the issue I had was that I was loading the script before the tab panels were loaded, therefore the active tab would be set, but the panel would not be shown.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: errors in console? btw you don't need to include the script, all scripts are compiled automatically

Comment: `var day = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"][new Date().getDay()]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @royhowie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your fiddle, code runs too early, before template is rendered. So you need to wrap your code within a function, and then run it inside your `Template.nav.onRendered` like this:

```
function initializeTabs() {
...
}
```

And then

```
Template.nav.onRendered(initializeTabs);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine using onRendered.

```
meteor create 32993732
cd 32993732
meteor add bootstrap
```

32993732.css:

```
body {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.tab-pane {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

32993732.html:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name="hello">
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#sunday" aria-controls="sunday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sunday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#monday" aria-controls="monday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tuesday" aria-controls="tuesday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tuesday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#wednesday" aria-controls="wednesday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wednesday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#thursday" aria-controls="thursday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Thursday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#friday" aria-controls="friday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Friday</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#saturday" aria-controls="saturday" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Saturday</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="sunday">Sunday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="monday">Monday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="thursday">Thursday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="friday">Friday</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="saturday">Saturday</div>
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

32993732.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.onRendered( function(){
    var day;

    switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0:
        day = "sunday";
        break;
        case 1:
        day = "monday";
        break;
        case 2:
        day = "tuesday";
        break;
        case 3:
        day = "wednesday";
        break;
        case 4:
        day = "thursday";
        break;
        case 5:
        day = "friday";
        break;
        case 6:
        day = "saturday";
        break;
    }

    $('.nav-tabs li a[href="#' + day + '"]').tab('show');

  });
}
```